# In django does it matter where the `class Meta:` declaration is placed?

Tags: mysql, django, macos, model, meta

By convention django places the `class Meta:` declaration second to last in the class definition, right before the `__unicode__` method definition. Is this required? I'm trying to trace an insidious error on Lion OSX where the case (capital/lower) of a `db_table = u'TableName'` statement is being ignored for some models. For some models `manage.py syncdb` creates mysql tables with the `lower()`ed table names and for others it uses the `db_table` case properly. The more complicated models, with custom `save()` and other methods are the ones that are converted to lowercase before creating mysql tables. I'm trying lots of code rearranging to see if that's the issue, but can't find documentation for the proper order of things, though I recall in the past somewhere that a position for `class Meta:` was specified.

Also tried both unicode literals for the db_table spec and single-byte string literals. Niether make a difference (for the working or the nonworking models)

Here's the relevant code:

grep -A5 -B2 _table 'entityorganizer/models.py'

```
    class Meta:
        db_table     = 'Entity'
        verbose_name_plural = "entities"
        ordering = ["map_status","type_name","name"] 
        get_latest_by = "updated"

--

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'EntityRelationship'
        ordering = ["to_entity","relationship_type"]
        unique_together = (('from_entity','to_entity','relationship_type'))
        get_latest_by = "updated"
        verbose_name = "relationship"

--

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Specialty'
        verbose_name_plural = u'specialties'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s'%(self.specialty)

--

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ZipCode'
        get_latest_by = "updated"

    def get_region(self):
        return REGION[region_id_v2-200][1] or 0

--

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Setting'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s = %s'%(self.name, self.value) #, self.updated)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your `class Meta` wherever you want in your models, so long as it matches the correct indentation.

Comment: That's what I assumed. Must be some other error in my model def or an inconsistency in how Lion and MAMP treats the case of table names. The only significant thing that's changed between working and nonworking is upgrade to Lion OSX on the server.

Comment: Try double checking your tabs?

Comment: tabs/indentation fine. works fine on Linux server, just not OSX Lion.

Comment: If you remove this particular app from your settings.py, does it work?  Are you sure the code is in sync with the osx + linux machines?  I'm just fishing.. it's hard to tell without seeing the exact setup/code.

Comment: yea, all other apps (and all other models within the same app) work fine on OSX. That's why I'm stumped and asked my goofy question about the order of the Meta definition.

Comment: good thought on making sure code is synced up. will double check that OSX isn't doing something goofy with line-endings or tab characters. the guy I'm helping uses a GUI to checkout code from git repo, so problem is probably in that process. hopefully he'll chime in soon with the exact error messages and code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the `class Meta:` position was indeed a red herring (as @sdolan made clear). Apparently MAMP or django stores meta data regarding the case of deleted tables somewhere outside of the tables themselves. Once we deleted the entire database and rebuilt, the `db_table` case was honored by mysql and `syncdb`